# How does $(x^2+ 1)^2 = (x+i)^2\cdot (x-i)^2?$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How can $(x^2 + 1)^2$ equal $(x+i)^2\cdot(x-i)^2?$ Please explain it in the simplest way. Thank you

Comment: $$x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i)$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint : all you need to know is $i^2=-1$ and

$$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)\text{ and }(a^2-b^2)^2=(a-b)^2(a+b)^2$$